# Confusion between polynomial in field and factorization.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider $f(x)=x^3+3x+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ and we can see that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ since it has no zeros in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

After I read this example and found out that there is a theorem which says,

"If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, then every non-constant polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ can be factored in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ into a product of irreducible polynomials."

However, we just saw that $f(x)=x^3+3x+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is irreducible even though $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is a field.

Comment: $f(x)$ is irreducible, so its factorization consists of one term, $f(x)$.

Comment: but factorization of f(x) is product of polynomials that have degree less than f?

Comment: @Nancy: There is no requirement that the polynomials have degree less than $f$. Consider the prime factorization of a single prime integer $p$. It has only one factor appearing, exactly analogous to this situation.

Comment: oh I was confused between factorization and "irreducible"... Thanks!

Comment: The product of all elements in a singleton set $\{ f \}$ is $\,f.\,$ The product of the empty set is $1$. Such conventions allows degenerate cases to be included in general theorems, as in the cited theorem.